# estimating sample size

Tags: pr.probability

Say there is a web service where I can request information about a random item.
For a request each item has an equal chance of being returned.

If I keep requesting items and record the number of duplicates and unique, how do I estimate the total number of items?

Comment: This question may get more interest, and be better suited to, http://stats.stackexchange.com 